# Close Tab in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs.I have link suppose  open tab now user right clicks on link and selects **open link in new tab** ,Now i have code in page **abc.html** like $window.close();.It is not working as expected i am getting Following Error `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it`.I googled on that i found **only browser windows created using JavaScript can be closed using JavaScript**.is there any way i can acheive my goal.

Thanks

Comment: I have never seen a website that closes the window for me, thank you Buddha!

Comment: Isn't that message pretty clear? Does it need to tell you... *"no there is no other way"* also? C'mon man...trust what the browser vendor tells you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because error message from browser vendor is very clear

Answer (score 2):

If the user has chosen to open it in a new tab, you [can't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) close it with JavaScript. However, if you use `window.open()`, you can close the opened window using JavaScript.

So the answer is **no**, unless you hack the user's computer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.
try this:

```
window.top.close();
```

Working for me on all three major browsers.

if it does not work try :

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

Comment: No. If you'll try in from the console you'll see **Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.**

Comment: open(location, '_self').close();     <- try this

Comment: I'll remove my downvote, but the OP specify that they need an alternative that will allow to close any window (Of Course it will work with your second example, because that's a window opened by you using JS)